MX204 and GRE Tunnel performance
I have a juniper mx204 with 20x bgp peers and 3x full table, i want to establish 5-10x GRE tunnel and each tunnel passes around ~1.5-2Gbps traffic, i want to know if gre tunnels impact on CPU or mx204 will handle gre on PFE (ASIC) ?

Tunnel interfaces (GRE included) are terminated on the PFE (ASIC). Using GRE tunnels themselves will not cause any adverse impact on RE or FPC CPU utilization.
That said, if your GRE tunnels resolve reachability over prefixes learned via BGP, then obviously you may have a bottleneck there. If that's the case, you could consider Route Prioritization.

In this case, if i have bgp session on a GRE tunnel (I want to have bgp with a ddos protected IP transit and announce my prefixes to them and I have less than 30x /24) I will face no problem and packets processing for gre will happen on asic there will be no impact on CPU, right?

For all intents and purposes you can think of it as a normal interface. Transit packets (i.e., packets not destined for something on the router itself) are forwarded as normal and not touched by the CPU.
